# Inner Join query using Doctrine 2.2

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have been dipping my feet in Doctrine 2.2 and has been following the Doctrine official site for getting familiar with it. I have been struck with converting this normal mysql query to DQL.

I have a sample database with two tables:

```
**Table 1**
fruits:
fruit_id | fruit_name | fruit_type

**Table 2**
country:
country_id | country_name | fruit_id
```

I wanted to fetch the name of the country/countries by giving the fruit name. Normally this works with mysql query

```
"SELECT c.country_name FROM country c
 INNER JOIN fruits f 
 WHERE f.fruit_name = 'Apple'";
```

Using doctrine I have created two classes Fruits and Country which are entities for the tables in the database. I have tried in this fashion:

```
$dql = "SELECT c.country_name FROM Model\Country c
        INNER JOIN Model\Fruits f ON (c.fruit_id = f.fruit_id)
        WHERE f.fruit_name = 'Apple'";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$result = $query->getArrayResult();
```

This is throwing me an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Semantical Error] line 0, col 76 near 'f ON (c.fruit_id': Error: Identification Variable Model\Fruits used in join path expression but was not defined before.' in .......
```

In case if somebody can throw some light on how one can write the inner joins using doctrine 2.2, would be helpful.

**EDIT:** 
In case if somebody who is a profi in Doctrine 2, can give a simple **working example** for one to many relationship using `Docblock Annotations` ion case of two tables where the primary key in first table is foreign key in another table. 
Thanks